# How can I pass data (image) from RecyclerView to a separate Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass data from a RecyclerView that contains a list of photos to a separate Activity that should show Details about the selected photo.
since im new to Kotlin, i've tried a lot and failed to come up with a solution.. I'd be thankful if anyone has a word on this.

**PhotosActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


    class PhotosActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos)

    val recyclerPhotos = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_photo)

    recyclerPhotos.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    recyclerPhotos.adapter = PhotosAdapter(getPhotosData(), this)
}

private fun getPhotosData(): List<PhotoModel>{
    return listOf(
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo1),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo2),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo3),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo4),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo5),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo6),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo7),
        PhotoModel(R.drawable.photo8)
    )
}
}
```

**PhotosModel.kt**

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp
import java.io.Serializable

data class PhotoModel(
    val image: Int,
): Serializable
```

**PhotosAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class PhotosAdapter(val listOfPhotos: List<PhotoModel>,
                val context: Activity): RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val img = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_test)
    init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, PhotoDetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("PHOTO", listOfPhotos[adapterPosition])
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotosAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listOfPhotos.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotosAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.img.setImageResource(listOfPhotos[position].image)

}

}
```

**PhotoDetailsActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.wallpaperapp

import android.app.WallpaperManager
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground

class PhotoDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var arrow: ImageView
lateinit var img: ImageView
lateinit var btn_set: Button
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
lateinit var manager: WallpaperManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_details)


    val selectedPhoto = intent.extras?.getSerializable("PHOTO") as PhotoModel

    arrow = findViewById(R.id.img_arrow)
    arrow.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, PhotosActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    img = findViewById(R.id.img_detail)
    btn_set = findViewById(R.id.btn_wallpaper)


    btn_set.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        fun setOnClickr(l: (View) -> Unit){
            setBackgroundd()
        }
    })

}
fun setBackgroundd() {

    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.layout.activity_photos)
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

    manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    manager.setBitmap(bitmap)
}
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Add it to the intent you use to start the activity.

Comment: Do I need to assign the layout ImageView id to the variable in which the image is stored?

Comment: The image resource id is enough.